# Pandas: Dict of data frames to unbalanced Panel

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary of DataFrame objects:

dictDF={0:df0,1:df1,2:df2}

Each DataFrame df0,df1,df2 represents a table in a specific date of time, where the first column identifies (like social security number) a person and the other columns are characteristics of this person such as

```
DataFrame df0

id Name      Age Gender Job        Income
10 Daniel    40  Male   Scientist  100
5  Anna      39  Female Doctor     250

DataFrame df1

id  Name      Age Gender  Job        Income 
67  Guto      35  Male    Engineer   100 
7   Anna      39  Female  Doctor     300
9   Melissa   26  Female  Student    36

DataFrame df2

id    Name     Age Gender Job     Income 
77 Patricia    30  Female Dentist 300 
9  Melissa     27  Female Dentist 250
```

Note that the id (social security number) identifies exactly the person. For instance, the same "Melissa" arises in two different DataFrames. However, there are two different "Annas".

In these dataFrames the number of people and the people vary over time. Some people is represented in all dates and others are represented only in a specific date of time.

Is there a simple way to transform this dictionary of data frames in an (unbalanced) Panel object, where the ids arise in all dates and if the data a given id is not available it is replaced by NaN?

Off course, I can do that making a list of all ids and then checking in each date if a given id is represented. If it is represented, then I copy the data. Otherwise, I just write NaN.

**I wonder if there an easy way using pandas tools.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a MultiIndex instead of a Panel.

First, add the period to each dataframe:

```
for n, df in dictDF.iteritems():
    df['period'] = n
```

Then concatenate into a big dataframe:

```
big_df = pd.concat([df for df in dictDF.itervalues()], ignore_index=True)
```

Now set your index to `period` and `id` and you are guaranteed to have a unique index:

```
>>> big_df.set_index(['period', 'id'])
               Name  Age  Gender        Job  Income
period id                                          
0      10    Daniel   40    Male  Scientist     100
       5       Anna   39  Female     Doctor     250
1      67      Guto   35    Male   Engineer     100
       7       Anna   39  Female     Doctor     300
       9    Melissa   26  Female    Student      36
2      77  Patricia   30  Female    Dentist     300
       9    Melissa   27  Female    Dentist     250
```

You can also reverse that order:

```
>>> big_df.set_index(['id', 'period']).sort_index()
               Name  Age  Gender        Job  Income
id period                                          
5  0           Anna   39  Female     Doctor     250
7  1           Anna   39  Female     Doctor     300
9  1        Melissa   26  Female    Student      36
   2        Melissa   27  Female    Dentist     250
10 0         Daniel   40    Male  Scientist     100
67 1           Guto   35    Male   Engineer     100
77 2       Patricia   30  Female    Dentist     300
```

You can even unstack the data quite easily:

```
big_df.set_index(['id', 'period'])[['Income']].unstack('period')
        Income          
period       0    1    2
id                      
5          250  NaN  NaN
7          NaN  300  NaN
9          NaN   36  250
10         100  NaN  NaN
67         NaN  100  NaN
77         NaN  NaN  300
```